# Changing the page header text in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

How do I change the default page header in a Windows 8 XAML application?  The question is simple, just I am still learning XAML.

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MainPageViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<!-- PageAdornerControl displays the back button and a page title -->
<Layout:PageAdornerControl
        Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
        Header="{Binding Header}">
```

I see Header as the text.  My first thought was to change {Binding Header} to {Binding }, however a mouse over on Header shows that as some valid whatever. Also, I would like to use the Visual Studio 2012 properties window to change the text.

Comment: Well, you can do two things:

Change the value of the `Header` property in your ViewModel or directly change the value of the Header property in the PageAdornerControl.

Comment: Thanks Nate, I see it.  I will give the steps in an answer, so that others can see.  It is not obvious, even after your comment.  I almost wrote you something else, but then I stumbled on it using your comments.  Thanks.  Winform development is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

There might be other ways, and I am still less than green with XAML, but here is one way using Nate's pageAdornerControl method.

1. Place the cursor on the Layout:PageAdornerControl in the XAML code area.
2. Go to the properties window, which should show the type as PageAdornerControl.
3. Scroll down to header
4. From the dropdown list, select Go to Source
5. You will now see another section of code highlighted.
6. Go to the properties window and the Header attribute will be the actual header text, which you can edit.